# Why is passing an ad-hoc created HashMap<> array as parameter ambiguous?

Tags: java, generics, ambiguous

consider this class example here:

```java
public class MyDAO extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport
{
    public int add(HashMap<...> mapping)
    {
        getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(
            "INSERT INTO ...",
            mapping.keySet().stream().map(t -> new HashMap<String, Object>()
                {{
                    // add some key/value pairs into map dependent on t
                }}
            ).toArray(HashMap[]::new));
    }
}
```

My IDE (IntelliJ) is fine with this construct, but compiling it via maven produces a compilation error saying the reference to batchUpdate is ambiguous. There are two `batchUpdate()` methods available:

- `batchUpdate(String, Map<String,?>[])`
- `batchUpdate(String, SqlParameterSource[])`

It looks like the compiler is only "seeing" an array but the lambda construct clearly produces a HashMap, so the first method should be chosen. When I create the HashMap before the call to `batchUpdate()` and pass it as a parameter, the compiler error won't show up.

```java
HashMap<String, Object>[] batchValues = ...; // same lambda construct here
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate("INSERT ...", batchValues);
```

What is happening here and why is happening that way? Both approaches should be syntactically valid.

Comment: Is IntelliJ configured to use the same version of Java compiler as maven uses?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes. It is only a single version of the JDK installed. `javac -version` yields `1.8.0_66`.